# How Can I Replicate This SQL Sub Query In Neo4j

Tags: subquery, neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and graph databases, but I have a background in relational databases.

My question a request for advice on how to replicate an SQL Server query efficiently in Neo4j.

I am starting a new project which I think is suited to Neo4j due to a number of friend-of-a-friend type relationships I will have to store. I am using Neo4j 1.8.1 and C# to write my application

One part of my project has a section which has a structure comparable to Twitter, and this is where I need help.

I will use a Twitter analogy to explain my problem:

I have a list of text blobs (tweets) and each blob can be in 0, 1 or many categories (hash tags). Unlike Twitter, I also have users which are linked to 0, 1 or many categories.

I conceive the graph looking something like this:

T = text blob node, C = category node, U = user node

```
T-------C-------U
 \_____/ \_____
 /     \       \
T-------C-------U
 \_____
       \
T-------C-------U
  _____/ \_____
 /             \
T               U
```

When the application is running, I estimate there will be about 10,000,000 records (I will probably archive any more than this), about 100 categories and about 1000 users.

Currently I have a simple SQL Server database to test this:

```
     __________         ______________        ___________       ______________      ________
    |Text      |       |TextCategory  |      |Category   |     |UserCategory  |    |User    |
    |----------|       |--------------|      |-----------|     |--------------|    |--------|
    |TextId    |-------|TextId        |------|CategoryId |-----|UserId        |----|UserId  |
    |Text      |       |CategoryId    |      |Name       |     |CategoryId    |    |Name    |
    |DateAdded |       |DateAdded     |      |-----------|     |--------------|    |--------|
    |----------|       |--------------|
```

By copying the DateAdded field from the Text table to the TextCategory table and adding indexes to the 2 linking tables, I can run the following query to return all text items belonging to a category that a user subscribes to ordered by date:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Text t
    INNER JOIN tc TextCategory ON tc.TextId = b.TextId
WHERE tc.CategoryId IN
(
    SELECT CategoyId
    FROM UserCategory
    WHERE UserId = @UserId
)
ORDER BY tc.AddedDate
```

In reality I would page the results but for simplicity, I have left this out.

How can I replicate this query in my Neo4j database efficeintly? Is a sub query like this possible in Cypher?

If I used something like this:

```
u-[:SUBSCRIBES_TO]->c<-[:BELONGS_TO]-t
```

(My Cypher skills are still quite infantile)

I could scan through the text nodes but I would not be able to use an index on the user. I would end up checking each text node to see if it was linked to the user.

If I scanned through all relationships linked to a user, I would not be able to take advantage of the date ordering index on the text nodes to page results avoid scanning all nodes to find the 10 earliest for example.

As I have mentioned I come from an RDBMS background and I am still thinking about this in a relational database way, so if I am wrong in my theories please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this translates quite directly to neo.
You could put the user nodes in an index and then query like you already stated:

```
start u=users(<USERID>) match u-[:SUBSCRIBES_TO]->c<-[:BELONGS_TO]-t return t order by t.AddedDate skip(<SKIPPED>) limit(<PAGESIZE>)
```

Unless i missed something you answered it already.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. What I am really concerned about is the speed and efficiency of this query. If I ran this query, is Neo4j scanning every text node that the user is linked to, then ordering them by date, then bringing back the range requested. A user may be linked to over 1,000,000 text nodes. Can an index be used to scan the text nodes in date order so that only the minimum required are scanned?

Comment: I am unsure about how this is optimized internally performance wise. Unfortunatly there is no equivalent of ordering indices in neo4j as far as i know. From my personal experience queries like this with multiple joins in SQL run very fast even for big numbers of nodes/relationships. Are you getting unreasonable performance on tests? If performance is a real concern it sometimes pays off to andcraft gremlin queries instead of using cypher.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and thank you for telling me that there are no ordering indices. The whole application is just on paper at the moment I just wanted to be sure that Neo4j was suitable for my needs. I will look more into Gremlin, it is something I have not studied until now.